# Can route model binding be used with RESTful controllers?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have been using [RESTful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) in my Laravel project.  By including:

```
Route::controller('things', 'ThingController')
```

in my routes.php, I can define functions in the `ThingController` like:

```
public function getDisplay($id) {
    $thing = Thing::find($id)
    ...
}
```

so that GETting the URL "...things/display/1" would automatically be directed to the controller function.  This seems pretty handy and has been working great for me so far.

I noticed many of my controller functions start with getting a model by id from the url, and I thought it would be nice to be able to use [route model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding) to do this for me instead. So I updated my routes.php to

```
Route::model('thing', 'Thing');
Route::controller('things', 'ThingController')
```

and changed the `ThingController` functions to

```
public function getDisplay($thing) {
    ...
}
```

I assumed this would magically work the way I wanted it to (like everything else I've tried so far in Laravel has) but unfortunately I get "Trying to get property of non-object" when I attempt to use `$thing` in the function.  Is this something that should be able to work and I have just done it wrong, or can route model binding only work with routes explicitly named in routes.php?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind with URI path, method name and just work only `show`, `edit` and `update` method, you can use [Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) to generate URI string which can define model binding.

In `routes.php` change to

```
Route::model('things', 'Thing');
Route::resource('things', 'ThingController');
```

You can use `php artisan routes` command to see all URIs

```
$ artisan routes | grep ThingController
GET|HEAD things                | things.index               | ThingController@index
GET|HEAD things/create         | things.create              | ThingController@create
POST things                    | things.store               | ThingController@store
GET|HEAD things/{things}       | things.show                | ThingController@show
GET|HEAD things/{things}/edit  | things.edit                | ThingController@edit
PUT things/{things}            | things.update              | ThingController@update
PATCH things/{things}          |                            | ThingController@update
```

After that you can threat parameter as `Thing` object without explicitly name route.

```
/**
 * Display the specified thing.
 *
 * @param  Thing  $thing
 * @return mixed
 */
public function show(Thing $thing)
{
    return $thing->toJson();
}
```

If you want to access `ThingController@show`, pass your model ID and Laravel will retrieve it automatically.

`http://example.com/things/1`

```
{"id":1,"type":"Yo!"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Route:resource and still provide other methods. Place the route you need just before that particular `Route::resource` line.
Eg:

```
Route::model('things', 'Thing');
Route::get('things/{things}/owner', 'ThingController@getOwner');
Route::resource('things', 'ThingController');
```

Then create the corresponding method in your controller.

```
public function getOwner($things) {
    return Response::json($things->owner()->get());
}
```

Here is the official documentation from the Laravel 4.2 docs:

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Adding Additional Routes To Resource Controllers

If it becomes necessary for you to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond the default resource routes, you should define those routes before your call to `Route::resource`:

```
Route::get('photos/popular');
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your Model like:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
  return 'slug';
}
```